# Несколько экземпляров класса используют общую переменную. Как правильно сделать?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь понять, как принято решать такую задачу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть несколько экземпляров класса, реагирующих на 'resize' окна. Для того, чтобы серия объектов не дергалась с каждым 'resize', я вешаю на 'resize' обработчик, который отрабатывает resize не чаще, чем раз в секунду, и в случае ресайза отправляет окну событие refreshed:

```html
    handleResize() {
        let resizeTimeout;
        return function() {
            if (!resizeTimeout) {
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    resizeTimeout = null;
                    console.log('Push refresh event');
                    let refreshedEvent = new Event('refreshed');
                    window.dispatchEvent(refreshedEvent);
                }, 1000);
            }
        };
    }
```

Обработчик должен создаваться вместе с созданием первого экземпляра. Но я не понимаю, где хранить сам обработчик, и как каждый из объектов будет понимать, что обработчик уже создан. Приходится создавать глобальную переменную и ее проверять. Насколько это хорошая практика, и как поступают в таком случае?

Comment: oн не глобальный; он просто очень близко к корню отображения; у него есть размер, и он его сообщает своим потомкам (по дереву)

Answer (score 1):

Глобальные переменные можно создавать, но один из принципов функционального программирования заключается в неизменности этих переменных. Если же необходимо изменить, тогда копируете переменную в другую в функции и возвращаете ее

Answer (score 0):

Если брать React, то я бы сделал Общий SizeProvider где-то близко к корню компонент, и провайдил бы из него контекст, а те, кому интересно использовали `useContex`.

При этом я могу себе представить и 2 провайдера на разные части экрана.
Или много (screen sharing / coworking).

Comment: еще пример -- picture-in-picture